# Flash receive sockets

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I was searching on google for it, I couldn't find it.
I would like to know how can I listen to sockets using actionscript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly in Flash. You can however do it through an AIR application starting in AIR 2.0. You can download the AIR 2.0 Beta here: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air2.html

I know that's not exactly the answer you were hoping for, but I hope it helps.

**EDIT:** As an extra note, I've done it in AIR 2, and it is pretty is easy to get up and running.

Comment: So How do people makes online games without receiving information from the server? o_o

Comment: Well typically, you would make a socket connect from Flash, not receive one. So you might have a Java based SocketServer running to handle the communication. You might want to explore the new peer-to-peer stuff in Player 10

Comment: Also note, if you wanted to create an AIR SocketServer, you can run it on a server that your Flash applications could connect to, basically exactly the same as you would with a JAVA solution.

Comment: I am talking about the nonoba api or others apis, how do the client receive information about the server?

Comment: Nonoba has a serverside application you communicate through. They are using one built on #C as appose to JAVA, but same idea.

Comment: In Flash you create socket and connect to the server side application. Once that connection is made, you can send/receive information. But you can not receive connections, only create, and rely on the server app to shuttle information between users.

Comment: Oh, I understand, I need a java server to forward the information to the main server?

Comment: No sorry, I'll try to be clearer. Basically you would have an application running (JAVA or similar). Your flash applications would connect to it. All data would go to this application, and it would share that data with any other players connected. The JAVA application IS the server.

Comment: What about this:
The java collect the information about the clients, then it sends it to the flash server.

Comment: Ya, that great solution, lets you stay entirely in AS

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Socket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) and [XMLSocket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) classes.

Comment: @Tenev: The security aspect is a bit complicated. I remember it requiring a lot of reading and trial and error on my part. This was before AIR, mind you.